# Kafka connector - Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to setup sink connector from amazon msk to s3,using confluent amazon kafka s3 sink connector plugin.

I am able to configure and after starting connector in distributed mode I don't see any errors in the logfile  but no data is being copied/written to s3.

I see below info in the logfile,but when the connector is running I don't see corresponding consumer group created/listed in kafka cluster.

[2022-05-15 06:36:53,744] DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-connect-cluster-sink-1, groupId=connect-cluster-sink] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition connect-offsets-9 at position FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[192.168.12.14:9094  (id: 1 rack: use1-az1)], epoch=0}} to node 192.168.12.14:9094 (id: 1 rack: use-az) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher:1245)

[2022-05-15 06:36:53,744] DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-connect-cluster-sink-1, groupId=connect-cluster-sink] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition connect-offsets-7 at position FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[192.168.12.14:9094  (id: 1 rack: use1-az1)], epoch=0}} to node 192.168.12.14:9094  (id: 1 rack: use-az) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher:1245)

Consumer.properties file

```
consumer.bootstrap.servers  =192.168.12.14:9094
consumer.group.id=connect-cluster-sink
consumer.sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
consumer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
consumer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
  username="<username>" \
  password="<password>";
```

connect-distributed.properties

```
group.id = connect-cluster-sink
bootstrap.servers = 192.168.12.14:9094
plugin.path = /usr/share/java
sasl.mechanism = SCRAM-SHA-512
security.protocol = SASL_SSL
```

consumer-config.properties

```
name=s3-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=topic-connect
flush.size=3
s3.bucket.name=connect-sink
s3.region=us-east-1
s3.part.size=5242880
storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
#format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
```

Please let me know if there is any config issues which is stopping data from being written to S3.